# How to silently auto-update an electron application that is installed via NSIS for all users / per-machine?

Tags: electron, nsis, windows-server, electron-builder

**Project:**
We have created an electron application that is shipped to our users (mostly using Windows) using an NSIS installer built with electron-builder.

**Scenario:**
Our users are companies who install our application into the "C:\Program Files" folder on a Windows Terminal Server for all of their staff. The staff - who is using our software and sees the related update notification after a new release - most of the times can not install the update because of a lack of necessary permissions.

**Question:**
We would like to not only solve the above problem but even go one step further: We would like our app to update itself silently. What possible solutions are there to make this possible in a scenario like the above?

Comment: HI @jmeinke, did you able to fix this ?. I am also stuck with this same problem

Comment: We've implemented a Windows service that checks for updates regularly and installs them in the background. For this to work, you have to run your app from a subversion folder. We had to modify our app and the installer scripts and test it extensively.

Comment: Thank you so much @jmeinke  I am using electron-updater and aws s3 for storing artifacts. so is windows service work with this configuration ? Is there any articles, documentation to achieve this, it helps me a lot. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do per-user installs instead then normal users will of course be able to write to the directory.

Another option is to switch to MSI. A signed MSI package can be patched by normal users without UAC elevation. This is called [User Account Control (UAC) Patching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/user-account-control--uac--patching).

A third option is to create a NT service that runs the installer. Services can be configured so that normal users can start them. A scheduled task might also work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Our customers do not want to do per-user installs because 1. they'd need to install our app on every client / user account 2. another program calls our app using a hardcoded path that does not support environment variables (it could be a batch file though).

The MSI option is interesting. Unfortunately, though it's not supported by electron-updater and we'd need to program such a mechanism by ourselves. Are there any ready-made solutions that you know?

About services: What if the exe runs on different user accounts and can not be overwritten because of this?

Comment: Could such an NT service kill all running instances (in all user sessions) of our app before starting the installation of the update? This currently sounds like the most promising solution to me.

Comment: The service can run as System and can access and kill in all sessions. If doing that is a good idea is another question...

Comment: I'll accept your answer because you're suggestions were helpful to us. We'll evaluate the different possibilities now. Thanks Anders!